# Two setState second rely on first

Tags: reactjs

I have this function that has two `setState`s, second one has to rely on the first one, how can I update the code to achieve that?

```
  makeHandleChange = name => contactID => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      contactInfo: prevState.contactInfo.filter(i => i.id !== contactID ),
    }));
    const searchMode =
      this.state.contactInfo.length === 0
        ? searchModes.noResultsPanel
        : searchModes.resultsPanel;
    this.setState({ searchMode });
  };
```

Comment: You can pass a callback to setState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `setState` need to use state updater function to queue them and avoid race conditions:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  contactInfo: prevState.contactInfo.filter(i => i.id !== contactID )
}));

this.setState(prevState => ({
  searchMode: prevState.contactInfo.length === 0
    ? prevState.searchModes.noResultsPanel
    : prevState.searchModes.resultsPanel
});
```

This way updater functions can be extracted into reusable functions.

Two `setState` calls can be merged into one call (as another answer already shows), but this is unnecessary:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const contactInfo = prevState.contactInfo.filter(i => i.id !== contactID );

  return {
    contactInfo,
    searchMode: contactInfo.length === 0
      ? prevState.searchModes.noResultsPanel
      : prevState.searchModes.resultsPanel
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you please give me an example on how to merge both `setState`

Comment: You're welcome. It's similar to what aseferov's answer shows. This is likely a good thing here because state update is short, but in case a single state update becomes too bulky, several `setState` are acceptable solution to keep the code readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one setState

```
makeHandleChange = name => contactID => {

    let filteredContactInfo = this.state.contactInfo.filter(i => i.id !== contactID )
    this.setState({
       contactInfo: filteredContactInfo,
       searchMode: !filteredContactInfo.length ? searchModes.noResultsPanel: searchModes.resultsPanel
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback of the first setState:

```
makeHandleChange = name => contactID => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    contactInfo: prevState.contactInfo.filter(i => i.id !== contactID)
  }), () => {
    this.setState({ searchMode: this.state.contactInfo.length === 0
      ? searchModes.noResultsPanel
      : searchModes.resultsPanel;
    });
  });
};
```